# В каком числе глагол поставить?

Tags: согласование, множественное-число

В данный момент меня интересует предложение «Обладает(речь о зубном порошке) выраженными вяжущим, антисептическим и болеутоляющим действиями»
Могут быть несколько верных вариантов?

Comment: Ну смотрите, если на слух вам все ок, значит как правило все и есть ок. Нацкорпус подтверждает правильность обоих вариантов. Другое дело, когда какой вариант предпочесть, может быть здесь есть какие-то установки. Надо подождать грамотеев.

Comment: А какой второй вариант правильный?

Comment: Обладает выраженным вяжущим, антисептическим и болеутоляющим действием.

Comment: @Диана Именно *глагол* в этом предложении может быть только в единственном числе: порошок (что дела**ет**?) облада**ет**.